# Buy all shares in multiplayer mode openttd?

Tags: openttd

Is there any way (an extension, plugin, etc) to buy whole companies in multiplayer mode in openttd? Doing a fusion of companies would be quite an interesting challenge.

Answer (score 2):

First, in order to enable buying shares, the server needs to have the relevant 'Competitors' option set (allow buying shares).

According to the [openTTD wiki](https://wiki.openttd.org/Buying_shares), even with this option on it is impossible to buy more than 75% of the shares from non-AI opponents or buy any shares at all from companies that are less than 6 years old.

Completely buying out a human opponent in multiplayer is disabled because code to transfer a client to another company server-side does not exist. You would have to patch the code for openTTD to gain this functionality. See also [this topic](https://www.tt-forums.net/viewtopic.php?t=52387).

In the original openTTD, your loan would be added to your company value. Two human players could expoit this as follows:

1. Player A repays his loan down to £10,000.
2. Player B buys 75% of player A's company, having £92,500 money and £100,000 loan.
3. Player A now loans up to £150,000.
4. Player B sells the shares for £112,500, now having £205,000 money and £100,000 loan. 
   £105,000 was just created from nothing.
5. Reverse the roles of player A and B. However, since B now can fluctuate his value between £105,000 and £255,000, A buys shares in B for £76,250 and sells them for £191,250 after B loans £150,000, leaving him with £115,000.

So in OpenTTD, the developers decided to 'subtract' loans from a company's value. Obviously, an empty player company still has some value, since it can loan a fixed amount of money. Thus the 6-year minimum to prevent you from obtaining a 75% share in the loan for only £3. It also prevents what's effectively unlimited lending.